# No node has same color as its children - recursion

Tags: python, recursion, tree

Given `binary tree` with 2 colors `(green,red)` decide if given tree is `Green-Red` tree.
One of the conditions for `Green-Red` tree is: `Each node has different color than its children`

```
def checkTree(node):
    if node is None:
        return
    //return checkTree(node.left) and checkTree(node.right) - not sure about this 
    if node has 1 child:
        if they are same color:
            return False
        return True
    if node has 2 child:
        if left children or right children has same color as node:
            return False
        return True
```

Problem is I do NOT know how to call a recursion here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can fill in some parts that you are missing that are to do with recursion, but the others I'll leave as your original pseudo code as an exercise.

```
def checkTree(node):
    if node has no children:  # pseudo code, FIXME
        return True   # Terminate the recursion here

    if node has 1 child:
        if they are same color:
            return False
        return checkTree(singleChild)  # you need code that will find the child, FIXME
    if node has 2 children:
        if left children or right children has same color as node:
            return False
        return checkTree(node.left) and checkTree(node.right)
```

The recursive parts here are:

1. Where `checkTree(n)` is called which recurses down a leg of the tree.
2. The final `return True` which terminates the recursion.

Plus, the couple of `return False` statements are optimisations which avoid whole legs when it becomes obvious that the tree does not meet the conditions.